# Three js performance

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, rendering, webgl

I started to work with three.js and webgl for a little project. I want to create a wardrobe model based on user input. You can find the project here:

http://jfeldmann.pf-control.de/threejs/

Without Materials and Shadows it renders pretty fast and the orbitting is very smooth, but if I enable the shadow map and add my materials it gets slower and slower. So my question is, if there are any performance issues or possible enhancements in my code. The Textures have a file-size between 10 and 70 KB.

Here is the main JS-Code:

```
var WIDTH = 800,
    HEIGHT = 600;

// set some camera attributes
var VIEW_ANGLE = 45,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 1,
    FAR = 10000;

// get the DOM element to attach to
// - assume we've got jQuery to hand
var $container = $('#container');

// create a WebGL/Canvas renderer, camera

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();   
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(  VIEW_ANGLE,
                                ASPECT,
                                NEAR,
                                FAR  );
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
var INTERSECTED;
var objects = [];

//Variables from Form

var stange, hoehe, breite, anzahl_tueren, mesh, schrank, door, door_1, door_2, door_3, plane, breite_hoehe_tiefe, material_selected, projector, raycaster;
var error_breite = document.getElementById('err_msg_breite');
var error_hoehe = document.getElementById('err_msg_hoehe');
var error_tiefe = document.getElementById('err_msg_tiefe');
var tiefe = 0;  
var mirrorCube, mirrorCubeCamera;


//Form-Data 
$("#submit_btn").bind("click", change);
$( "#opacity_slider" ).change(function() {    
        door_1.material.transparent = true;
        door_1.material.opacity = document.getElementById('opacity_slider').value/100;
        door_2.material.transparent = true;
        door_2.material.opacity = document.getElementById('opacity_slider').value/100;
        door_3.material.transparent = true;
        door_3.material.opacity = document.getElementById('opacity_slider').value/100;
});

//Materials 
var material_basic = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/basic.jpg'), color: 'white'});
material_selected = material_basic;

var material_schrank = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/basic.jpg')});

var material_door_1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/basic.jpg')});
var material_door_2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/basic.jpg')});
var material_door_3 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/basic.jpg')});

var material_eiche = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/eiche.jpg')});    
var material_buche = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/buche.jpg')});    
var material_birke = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/birke.jpg')});
var material_mirror = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ shading: THREE.SmoothShading, map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('img/mirror.jpg')});  

//Lights
var pointLight_front = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xaaaaaa, 0.6 ); 
var pointLight_back = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xaaaaaa ); 


function change(){      

    objects = [];   

    scene.remove(schrank);
    scene.remove(door);
    scene.remove(pointLight_front);
    scene.remove(stange);       

    if(document.getElementById('breite').value<=400){       
        breite = parseInt(document.getElementById('breite').value,10);
        error_breite.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else error_breite.innerHTML = "Maximale Breite 400cm.";

    if(document.getElementById('hoehe').value<=300){        
        hoehe = parseInt(document.getElementById('hoehe').value,10);
        error_hoehe.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else error_hoehe.innerHTML = "Maximale Höhe 300cm.";

    if(document.getElementById('tiefe').value<=90){     
        tiefe = parseInt(document.getElementById('tiefe').value,10);
        error_tiefe.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else error_tiefe.innerHTML = "Maximale Tiefe 90cm.";    

    anzahl_tueren = parseInt(document.getElementById('anzahl_tueren').value,10);

    breite_hoehe_tiefe = Math.max(breite,hoehe,tiefe);

    //Floor                 
    var ground = new THREE.CubeGeometry( breite_hoehe_tiefe*10, 1, breite_hoehe_tiefe*10 );
    var white_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xfafafa, opacity : 1 } );
    plane = new THREE.Mesh(ground, white_material);
    plane.position.y = -1;      
    plane.receiveShadow = true; 

    //Schrank Basis
    var basis_geo = new THREE.CubeGeometry( breite, hoehe, tiefe );
    var basis_mesh = new THREE.Mesh( basis_geo );
    basis_mesh.position.z = -10;
    var basis_bsp = new ThreeBSP( basis_mesh );

    var schrank_width = 10;

    var basis_inner_geo = new THREE.CubeGeometry( breite-schrank_width, hoehe-schrank_width, tiefe+schrank_width );
    var basis_inner_mesh = new THREE.Mesh( basis_inner_geo );
    basis_inner_mesh.position.z = 0;
    var basis_inner_bsp = new ThreeBSP( basis_inner_mesh );

    var subtract_bsp = basis_bsp.subtract( basis_inner_bsp );
    schrank = subtract_bsp.toMesh( material_schrank );
    schrank.position.y = (hoehe/2); 
    schrank.castShadow = true;
    schrank.receiveShadow = true;       

    //Kleiderstange           
    if(document.getElementById('kleiderstange_check').value == 1){
        var stange_geo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 3, 3, breite-schrank_width, 8, 1 );
        stange = new THREE.Mesh(stange_geo, material_basic);
        stange.rotation.z = 90*Math.PI/180;
        stange.position.y = hoehe-40;
        document.getElementById("data_test").innerHTML = "Stange: Ja"+document.getElementById('kleiderstange_check').value;
    }
    else document.getElementById("data_test").innerHTML = "Stange: Nein"+document.getElementById('kleiderstange_check').value;

    //Türen 
    var door_width = 5;
    var door_seperation = 0.5;
    var door_geo = new THREE.CubeGeometry( ((breite-schrank_width)/anzahl_tueren)-door_seperation, hoehe-schrank_width, door_width );       
    door = new THREE.Object3D();
    door.position.z = (tiefe/2)-schrank_width-(door_width/2);

    if (anzahl_tueren==1) {
        door_1 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_1);
        door_1.position.z = 0;
        door_1.position.x = 0;                  
        door_1.castShadow = true;
        door_1.receiveShadow = true;
        door.add(door_1);
    }

    //add new door to door Mesh!!
    if (anzahl_tueren==2){
        door_1 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_1);
        door_1.position.z = 0;              
        door_1.castShadow = true;
        door_1.receiveShadow = true;
        door.add(door_1);           
        door_1.position.x = ((breite-(schrank_width))/4*(-1))-(door_seperation/4);          

        door_2 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_2);
        door_2.position.z = 0;
        door_2.position.x = ((breite-(schrank_width))/4)+(door_seperation/4);
        door_2.castShadow = true;
        door_2.receiveShadow = true;
        door.add(door_2);               
    }
    if (anzahl_tueren==3){

        door_1 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_1);
        door_1.position.z = 0;              
        door_1.castShadow = true;
        door_1.receiveShadow = true;
        door.add(door_1);           
        door_1.position.x = ((breite-(schrank_width))/3*(-1))-(door_seperation/4);          

        door_2 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_2);
        door_2.position.z = 0;
        door_2.position.x = 0;
        door_2.castShadow = true;
        door_2.receiveShadow = true;    
        door.add(door_2);   

        door_3 = new THREE.Mesh(door_geo, material_door_3);
        door_3.position.z = 0;
        door_3.position.x = (((breite-(schrank_width))/3)+(door_seperation/4));
        door_3.castShadow = true;
        door_3.receiveShadow = true;    
        door.add(door_3);   

    }
    door.position.y = (hoehe/2);
    door.castShadow = true;
    door.receiveShadow = true;  

    // set Light position
    pointLight_front.position.x = breite;
    pointLight_front.position.y = hoehe+500;
    pointLight_front.position.z = tiefe+300;
    pointLight_front.shadowCameraNear = 20; 
    pointLight_front.shadowCameraFar = 5000;    
    pointLight_front.shadowBias = 0.001;

    pointLight_front.shadowCameraLeft = -breite_hoehe_tiefe;
    pointLight_front.shadowCameraRight = breite_hoehe_tiefe;
    pointLight_front.shadowCameraTop = breite_hoehe_tiefe;
    pointLight_front.shadowCameraBottom = -breite_hoehe_tiefe;

    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.near = pointLight_front.shadowCameraNear;
    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.far = pointLight_front.shadowCameraFar;       
    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.left = pointLight_front.shadowCameraLeft;
    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.right = pointLight_front.shadowCameraRight;
    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.top = pointLight_front.shadowCameraTop;
    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.bottom = pointLight_front.shadowCameraBottom;

    pointLight_front.shadowCamera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    objects.push(schrank);
    objects.push(door.children[0]); 
    objects.push(door.children[1]); 
    objects.push(door.children[2]); 
    objects.push(stange);   
}   


init();
animate();

function init() {       

    projector = new THREE.Projector();
    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();  

    // the camera starts at 0,0,0 so pull it back
    camera.position.set(0,500,500);

    // start the renderer
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xfafafa );
    renderer.sortObjects = false;
    // to antialias the shadow
    renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
    renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

    // attach the render-supplied DOM element
    $container.append(renderer.domElement);          

    // and the camera
    scene.add(camera);

    // create a point light     
    pointLight_front.castShadow = true;
    pointLight_front.shadowDarkness = 0.07;
    pointLight_front.shadowMapWidth = 4096;
    pointLight_front.shadowMapHeight = 4096;    

    //make Light Cone visible to camera
    //pointLight_front.shadowCameraVisible = true; 

    pointLight_back.position.set( -150, 200, 250 );

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentMouseClick, false );
    //window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}

function onWindowResize() {

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

}

function onDocumentMouseClick( event ) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( (event.clientX-7) / WIDTH ) * 2 - 1; 
    mouse.y = 1 - ( (event.clientY-7) / HEIGHT ) * 2;
    //client.X / client.Y - 7 berücksichtigt den margin der body, der den canvas verschiebt

    // find intersections

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

    raycaster.set( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {              
        INTERSECTED = intersects[0].object;
        INTERSECTED.material.map = material_selected.map;

    } else {    
        //document.getElementById("data_test").innerHTML = "not intersected";           
    }

}

function animate() {      

  // Read more about requestAnimationFrame at http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);      
  scene.add(pointLight_front);
  scene.add(pointLight_back);
  scene.add(plane);
  scene.add(schrank);
  scene.add(door);
  scene.add(stange);
  render();
}

function render(){    

  // Render the scene.    
  renderer.render(scene, camera);     
  controls.update();    
}
```

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Look at your animation loop. How many children does your scene have?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but why where you continually adding new objects on every animation pass?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/GUI-Controller.html controls, you can change a little lighter sizes, other exampple: http://all.develoteca.com/builder/?model=book